# append on c (pointers of pointers)

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, function-declaration

I just started learning C language, and I can't fully understand why we should use pointers of pointers in order to append an element into the table (*tab).
here's the code :

```
#include "append.h"

int append(int ** tab, size_t *size, int value){
    int *nouveauTab = realloc(*tab, (*size + 1) * sizeof(int));
    if (nouveauTab == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    *tab = nouveauTab;
    (*tab)[*size] = value;
    (*size)++;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It kind of depends on what `tab` points at to begin with. You need to provide a bit of context.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Because you want to change the value of a pointer in the caller of `append`. That happens here: `*tab = nouveauTab;`

The code calling your `append` function will look something like:

```
int* table = NULL;
size_t table_size = 0;
if (append(&table, &table_size, 42) == 0)
{
    puts("append failed");
}
else
{
    printf(size is now %zu and element %zu is %d", table_size, table_size-1, table[table_size-1]);
}
```

So your code expects that `append` (on success) will change the value of both `table` and `table_size`. That requires that you pass the function pointers to these two variables.

If you did it **without** usinb pointers, i.e. like:

```
if (append(table, table_size, 42) == 0)
```

the function would not be able to change their values as C would just pass a copy of their current values.

A simple example using `int`

```
void foo(int x)
{
    x = x + 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

int x = 42;
printf("%d\n", x);
foo(x);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

will print

```
42
43
42  <--- x not changed by `foo` because we passed the value of x (i.e. 42)
```

but with this:

```
void foo(int* x)
{
    *x = *x + 1;
    printf("%d\n", *x);
}

int x = 42;
printf("%d\n", x);
foo(&x);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

it will print

```
42
43
43  <--- x was changed by `foo` because we passed a pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

If not to use pointer to pointer then the pointer tab will be passed by value. That is the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer. It will stay unchanged because it is its copy that was changed within the function.

So you need to pass the pointer by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object (a pointer is an object) indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer the function will have a direct access to the original object. In the case of your function to the original pointer like

```
*tab = nouveauTab;
```